# Phonegap + JQuery does not connect to internet

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cordova

I have been unable to successfully figure out why $.ajax refuses to connect to the Internet in Phonegap. The same code runs well in a standard HTML file. Access Origin is set to *.

Originally I thought Phonegap was refusing a connection to the Internet. However, it loads JQuery and JQuery Mobile remotely (by link tag). JQuery continues to return an error. Tested in JBoss Developer Studio (PG 4.1.2) and PG by commandline 4.3.

The error returned by stringifying the error object

```
error: {"readyStaate":4,"responseText":"{\n \"code\":
\"ENOTFOUND\",\n \"errno\":\"ENOTFOUND\",\n \"syscall\":\:getaddrinfo\"\n}","responseJSON":{"code":"ENOTFOUND","errno":"ENOTFOUND","syscall":"getaddrinfo"},"status":500,"statusText":"error"}
```

The Javscript used:

```
var app = {
// Application Constructor
initialize: function() {
    this.bindEvents();

},
bindEvents: function() {
    document.addEventListener('load', this.onDeviceLoad, false);
    document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);

},

onDeviceLoad: function() {
    window.isAndroid = navigator.userAgent.match(/(android)/gi) != null;

},

onlineEvent: function() {

},

offlineEvent: function() {

},

onDeviceReady: function() {
    app.receivedEvent('deviceready');
    // online/offline must be set in onDeviceReady
    document.addEventListener('online', this.onlineEvent , false);
    document.addEventListener('offline', this.offlineEvent , false);

    $.ajax({
      method: "POST",
      url: "http://www.someserver/server.php",
      data: { name: "John", location: "Boston" }
    })
      .done(function( msg ) {
        alert( "Data Saved: " + msg.posts );
        console.log('NETWORK' + msg.posts);
    })
      .fail(function(error) {
        alert("error: " + JSON.stringify(error));
    });
},
receivedEvent: function(id) {

}    
};

app.initialize();
```

Edit: I am aware of what the 500 error is. I have tested the server. It works fine with HTML5 and the same JQuery AJAX call. My hunch is that there is something with Phonegap; between the JQuery Client call and the server that is causing the error.

Edit2: The server name is private. The string is set to a real server on my actual code.

Comment: `url: "http://www.someserver/server.php"` - is that... right?

Comment: I changed the server name.

Answer (score 2):

jQuery doesn't "connect to the internet". It's just a JavaScript library. The 500-status response you're getting is telling you that the server you're trying to POST to is erroring:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#5xx_Server_Error

http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html

Comment: I should have stated I know what a 500 error is. someserver/server.php is set to a real server, the name is private so I changed it.

Comment: I realize `someserver` is a fake example URL you gave, but you still pasted a 500 response code above, meaning your *real* server is returning that response.